# unable to install applications from software centre. Installation failing

Tags: kernel

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 170318 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oem-kernel-cmdline (1.4kittyhawk7) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
postrm called with unknown argument `remove'
dpkg: error processing package oem-kernel-cmdline (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-kernel-cmdline
Error in function:
```

Comment: tried updating and upgrading but couldn't complete due to oem-kernel-cmdline error....so please what should i do now..??

Comment: Did you try to start with some older versions of kernel? Or is this a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

Now We try method 2

We are try remove & reinstall Software center.

To remove Software Center:

```
1. sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

2. sudo apt-get autoremove software-center

To re-install Software Center:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install software-center

or you can use single command for remove & reinstall Software Center

sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center

Now this will work & after this method work vote up the answer.
Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for helping but it still didn't work--raja@Avijit-Singha-Roy:~$ sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center................
Removing oem-kernel-cmdline (1.4kittyhawk7) ...
postrm called with unknown argument `remove'
dpkg: error processing package oem-kernel-cmdline (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-kernel-cmdline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score -1):

First of all run this commands on terminal

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get upgrade`

`$ sudo apt-get autoclean`

This commands will try to fix broken packages if any and also install required library files if missed.

After that install Synaptic Package Manager, Using this  you can add/remove/update/fix-broken packages very easily.

Install Synaptic Package Manager by using following command

`$ sudo apt-get install synaptic`

This will help you
best of luck.

Comment: "This commands will try to fix broken packages" No they won't, they will, update the sources list, upgrade the main system packages and then remove useless packages, to fix broken packages, you w0ould run `apt-get install -f`

Comment: still having the same error code                                                                 (Removing oem-kernel-cmdline (1.4kittyhawk7) ...
postrm called with unknown argument `remove'
dpkg: error processing package oem-kernel-cmdline (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-kernel-cmdline)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)